# Accessibility for a select tag that dynamically changes the URL of the following anchor tag

Tags: accessibility, screen-reader

I have a simple anchor element and a script (not shown) that will dynamically change the URL of the anchor element when the select tag is changed (to the url in the data-url attribute):

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a site</option>
    <option value="Google" data-url="https://google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="Stackoverflow" data-url="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</option>
    <option value="Example" data-url="https://example.com">Example</option>
</select>

<a href="#">Go to site</a>
```

I'm curious if this would make sense from an accessibility standpoint or if there's some aria attributes that I should use on the anchor/select tag that would help a user understand the purpose of the select tag here.

Would it make more sense to wrap everything in a form tag and change the action attribute dynamically and have the anchor change into a submit button/input?

```
<form action="<dynamically change this>" method="get">
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a site</option>
        <option value="Google" data-url="https://google.com">Google</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Go to site</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one of the `<option>` elements as the label of the `<select>` is generally not encouraged.  Once the user chooses an `<option>`, their label is gone and they might not understand what the dropdown is for.  It's always recommended to have a separate `<label for="id">` for the `<select>` ([see WCAG 3.3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#labels-or-instructions)).

Other than that, your two examples are ok.  Having a link instead of a button is slightly better because links are accepted as navigating you somewhere whereas a button with "go to site" is more of an "action" thing.  Using a link allows the user to use the browser's "back" button to go back to where they were.  The button won't allow that (unless you write JS to force it to work).

> I'm curious if this would make sense from an accessibility standpoint or if there's some aria attributes that I should use on the anchor/select tag that would help a user understand the purpose of the select tag here.

This comes down to my first point.  A sufficient label for the `<select>` should have enough detail to describe what the `<select>` is for so the user understands its purpose.